# The count badges on the activity tabs are breaking social distancing rules

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, activity-tab

As of this morning, the activity badges on the user Activity page have moved to be right next to the relevant tab name:

[image]   [image]

This movement makes it harder to read the tab name, could it please be returned to the way it was?

Comment: This is network wide. A little more space between the blue box and word would help.

Comment: Duplicate on MSE: [Recent misalignment in activity tabs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359598/294055)

Comment: That is clearly breaking social distancing rules ...

Comment: Please maintain a distance of at least six pixels from other elements.

Comment: But, it is good to see it's wearing that nice blue mask!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for the report!

Starting with the next build, the badges will maintain a safe distance of two <s>meters</s> pixels from their corresponding tab labels.

Comment: Thanks - much easier to read again. And we don't have to worry about transmission of pixelitis or the like :)